# Good to have a static reference to foreground activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-alertdialog, android-lifecycle

Is it good practice to have a static reference to foreground activity? eg:

```
public static Activity currentActivity = null;
```

This question is straight forward but I could not find much information on that. I am doing Xamarin Android - writing android apps in C#, so I get lots of tasks (background thread), and I wanna make a dialog but I do not have reference to the foreground activity whatsoever.

So what I am doing now is have a static reference to it, setting and unsetting the reference inside activitylifecyclecallbacks so it gets triggered at every activity, then putting a mutex around setter of the reference to ensure safety under extremely weird conditions..

This seems a bit hackish to me, but getting the current activity is really unnecessarily hard, and the methods I am dealing with are defined by interfaces used by IocContainers across all WPF, Android, iOS apps so I really cant pass activities around because I cant change method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bad idea to me:

- lots of extra code to manage the state of that static variable
- maintenance developers will hate you when debugging this

Why not have the background task fire an event? Then, have the foreground activity subscribe to the event and create the dialog. This way, if there is no foreground activity (or the foreground activity doesn't care), then nothing happens. You'll swap the code for managing the static with code for setting up the event handlers, but that will probably be easier to maintain/debug.

Comment: Yeh I saw the event approach and it seemed right, but we have a helper for making alert dialogues so the dialogues it makes can really show up in any activities, and we have 20+ activities so adding event handling to all of them is a lot of duplicate code..